# how can i get systemd files to work on wls ubuntu 20.04

Tags: linux, windows-subsystem-for-linux, systemd, ubuntu-20.04

I created a service file named *pointless.service* but when I run
 `sudo systemctl start pointless` it returned 
`System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate. Failed to connect to bus: Host is down` 
when I also tried `sudo service pointless start`
but it returned `pointless: unrecognized service`.
i am using wsl ubuntu 20.04
the above commands work for installed software like Nginx, Redis e.t.c. but it isn't working for any of my files

Comment: Are you using Windows 10 1909 (18363.836) and WSL 1?  The Ubuntu 20.04 app is currently broken -- see [this link](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-20-04-and-wsl-1/15291).  You may want to try Windows 10 2004 when available and WSL 2 with Ubuntu 20.04.